# Android invalidate View from other class

Tags: java, android

I have two classes MyView and MyThread and want to repaint the view every few miliseconds from a timer in MyThread class. 
The timer starts running but my View will not be repainted and i dont't understand why. Here is my Code:

MyView:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView{


private MainActivity mainActivity;
private Random random = new Random();

public MyView(Context context) {
super(context);
mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),
            random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
  }
}
```

MyThread:

```
 public class MyThread implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Timer timer = new Timer();
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private MyView myView;

public MyThread(Context context) {
   mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
   myView = new MyView(context);
   timer.schedule(new TimerThread(),50,50);
}

class TimerThread extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("Log","Timer run");
                myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                myView.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dont create a new reference at MyThread with new MyView, you have to pass as argument the reference you already have. Also, I'm not sure but you can call invalidate from other Thread

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more, now a Nullpointerexception is thrown if i remove this new MyView().

Comment: Update your constructor as public MyThread(Context context, View reference) so you use the reference to call the methods

Comment: Now it's works. Instead of extending from Surfaceview i extend from View